# complex number wrong output

Tags: c++, oop

I write this code with a class named Complex with the following methods:

a. Complex() // Default constructor returning 0

b. Complex(float im, float real)

c. float getImaginary() const

d. float getReal() const

e. Complex add(const Complex& rhs) const

f. Complex subtract(const Complex& rhs) const

g. Complex multiply(const Complex& rhs) const

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Complex {
    private:
        float real;
        float imaginary;
    public:
        Complex();
        Complex(float real=0, float im=0);
        float GetReal() const;
        float GetImaginary() const;
        Complex Add(const Complex &rhs) const;
        Complex Subtract(const Complex &rhs) const;
        Complex Multiply(const Complex &rhs) const;
        void SetReal(float r);
        void SetImaginary(float i);
};
    Complex::Complex()
    {
        real=imaginary=0;
    }

    Complex::Complex(float realpart, float imaginarypart) 
    {
    SetReal(real);
    SetImaginary(imaginarypart);
    }

    void Complex::SetReal(float r) 
    {
    real = r;
    }

    void Complex::SetImaginary(float i) 
    {
        imaginary = i;
    }

    float Complex::GetReal() const
    {
        return real;
    }

    float Complex::GetImaginary() const {
        return imaginary;
    }

    Complex Complex::Add(const Complex &rhs) const {
    return Complex(GetReal() + rhs.GetReal(), GetImaginary() + rhs.GetImaginary());
    }

    Complex operator+(const Complex &rhs1, const Complex &rhs2) {
    return rhs1.Add(rhs2);
    }

    Complex Complex::Subtract(const Complex &rhs) const 
    { 
    return Complex(GetReal() - rhs.GetReal(), GetImaginary() - rhs.GetImaginary());
    }

    Complex operator-(const Complex &rhs1, const Complex &rhs2) 
    {
    return rhs1.Subtract(rhs2); 
    }

    Complex Complex::Multiply(const Complex &rhs) const
    {
    return Complex(GetReal() * rhs.GetReal(), GetImaginary() * rhs.GetImaginary());
    }
Complex operator*(const Complex &rhs1, const Complex &rhs2) 
    {
    return rhs1.Multiply(rhs2);
    }

int main() 
{
    Complex c();
    Complex x(-2,4);
    Complex y(5,6);
    Complex z = x + y;
    cout << z.GetReal() << '+' << z.GetImaginary() << 'i' << endl;

       Complex e = x - y;
    cout << e.GetReal() << '+' << e.GetImaginary() << 'i' << endl;

    Complex r = x * y;
    cout << r.GetReal() << '*' << r.GetImaginary() << 'i' << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

but i take these output

> 8.99944e-039+10i

> 8.99944e-039+-2i

> 8.99944e-039*24i

Can somebody help me for this error ?

Comment: you get the same error for `int main(){ int x; int x; }`. You can only declare one variable with same name in the same scope. Do you not understand what the error says?

Comment: yes i cant understand and i cant fix can u rewrite this ?

Comment: why you cannot fix it? The error is about different objects having the same name, you can give them different names. Or if you actually wanted to use the same `z` declare it only once

Comment: okay i change this and i take this outputs "8.99944e-039+10i 
8.99944e-039+-2i
8.99944e-039*24i" i thnik these are wrong

Comment: `SetReal(real);` in the constructor should be `SetReal(realpart);`. `real` is the member you want to initialize with the function call.

Comment: thats a different problem. The question you asked here is unrelated to your `Complex` class (as I wrote you would get same error with `int`). When your `Complex` class is broken, thats a different question. When you get unexpected output you should include input, output and expected output in the question.

Comment: Multiplying 2 complex numbers is NOT real1*real2 + i * imag1*imag2.

Comment: @mch i used SetReal(realpart); now , any new problem did u see ?

Comment: I can't even tell what this question is asking now. There's an accepted answer to a question you no longer ask, and the question instead shows some results without saying what you expected instead. If you have a different question, post it as a separate question - this isn't a discussion board.

Comment: Do you have some reason not to use `std::complex`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 issues in your code:

```
Complex::Complex(float realpart, float imaginarypart) 
{
    SetReal(realpart);
    SetImaginary(imaginarypart);
}
```

causes the warning:

```
<source>:24:28: warning: unused parameter 'realpart' [-Wunused-parameter]
   24 |     Complex::Complex(float realpart, float imaginarypart)
      |
```

Fix it by passing `realpart` to `SetReal` or rather use the member initializer list:

```
Complex::Complex(float realpart, float imaginarypart) : real(realpart),imaginary(imaginarypart)
{}
```

Next, this:

```
Complex c();
```

is the most vexing parse. It declares a function named `c` taking no parameters and retuning a `Complex`. It is not declaring a variable `c` of type `Complex`. Write

```
 Complex c;
 Complex c{};
```

to call the default constructor. However, you class has two default constructors:

```
    Complex();  
    Complex(float real=0, float im=0);
```

A default constructor is one that can be called without parameters and thats the case for both of these. Hence you currently cannot default construct a `Complex`, the constructors are ambigoous. I read your assignemnt as requiring you to provide two constructors:

```
    Complex();  
    Complex(float real, float im);  // no defaults !!
```

Then you will be able to default construct a `Complex` via `Complex c;` or `Complex c{};` (but not via `Complex c();` because thats a function declaration).

After fixing those, I get almost reasonable looking output: https://godbolt.org/z/x4xG8xzTf

Finally, your formula for multipliying two complex numbers is wrong. I'll leave that for you to fix it.

Comment: i cant understand Complex c;
 Complex c{}; and  multipliying two complex numbers is wrong. my output is fine ? can u help me with more detail?

Comment: @MertEmreÖnen google: most vexing parse. And try to multiply `i` with `i`, result should be `-1`, but your result is `i`

Comment: okay i fixed -1 @largest_prime_is_463035818 with used `cout << r.GetReal() << '*' << "-" << r.GetImaginary() << endl;` and i googled most vexing parse i thnik is not important for me im just beginner in c++.

Comment: @MertEmreÖnen it is important for you to understand that `Complex c();` is wrong, because it isn't doing what you think it does. You didnt really fix it, you just cheated by printing different output, and even then the output is wrong. `0+1i * 0+1i` is `-1+0i` not `0+-1i`

Comment: if i use `Complex c{c()};` is that true? and yes u right i cant find good solution for multiplexing.

Comment: @MertEmreÖnen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number

Comment: i know this but i dont know how can implement i^2 = - 1 i know i asked so much but i need this also Complex c{(c)}; true? @largest_prime_is_463035818

Comment: @MertEmreÖnen "Complex c{c()}; true?" I dont understand what you mean. All I am trying to tell you is that `Complex c();` is wrong, and you should write `Complex c;` or `Complex c{};` to default contruct a `Complex`. `Complex c{c()};` doesnt make sense. For multiplication of complex numbers see the wiki article, there is a section on multiplication that has all you need

Comment: but if write complex c; or complex c{}; i have **Class "complex" has more than one default constructor** error.and i cannot implement complex multiplication i understand in wiki but i cant write :/ @largest_prime_is_463035818

Comment: @MertEmreÖnen sorry I didnt notice the issue with the default contructor before. See edit of the answer. Anyhow in your `main` you can simply remove the line `Complex c();` you don't need it.

Comment: thanks for all help i wanna ask final quesiton i know worng but `cout << r.GetReal() << '*' << "-" << r.GetImaginary() << endl;` or `cout << r.GetReal() << '*' << r.GetImaginary() << 'i' << endl;` which is better?

Comment: @MertEmreÖnen `cout << r.GetReal() << '*' << "-" << r.GetImaginary() << endl;` is a lie. You are not printing the value or `r` on the screen when you insert that `-`.

Comment: i know so cout << r.GetReal() << '*' << r.GetImaginary() << 'i' << endl; is better right ?

Comment: @MertEmreÖnen sorry, dont get me wrong, but the answer to that question is useless for you if you cannot answer it yourself. Consider you want to print the value of some `int x = 42;`, would you consider it correct to write `std::cout << "-" << x;` ?!?

Comment: yes sir i know i write both of them wrong.